# Why does Mypy think adding two Jax arrays returns a numpy array?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, jax

Consider the following file:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp

def test(a: jnp.ndarray, b: jnp.ndarray) -> jnp.ndarray:
    return a + b
```

Running `mypy mypytest.py` returns the following error:

```
mypytest.py:4: error: Incompatible return value type (got "numpy.ndarray[Any, dtype[bool_]]", expected "jax._src.numpy.lax_numpy.ndarray")
```

For some reason it believes adding two `jax.numpy.ndarray`s returns a NumPy array of *bools*. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in MyPy, or Jax's type annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least statically, `jnp.ndarray` is a subclass of `np.ndarray` with very minimal modifications

```
class ndarray(np.ndarray, metaclass=_ArrayMeta):
  dtype: np.dtype
  shape: Tuple[int, ...]
  size: int

  def __init__(shape, dtype=None, buffer=None, offset=0, strides=None,
               order=None):
    raise TypeError("jax.numpy.ndarray() should not be instantiated explicitly."
                    " Use jax.numpy.array, or jax.numpy.zeros instead.")
```

As such, it inherits `np.ndarray`'s method type signatures.

I guess the runtime behaviour is achieved via the `jnp.array` function. Unless I've missed some stub files or type trickery, the result of `jnp.array` matches `jnp.ndarray` simply because `jnp.array` is untyped. You can test this out with

```
def foo(_: str) -> None:
   pass

foo(jnp.array(0))
```

which passes mypy.

So to answer your questions, I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It's a bug in the sense that it's probably not what they mean, but it's not actually incorrect because you do get an `np.ndarray` when you add `jnp.ndarray`s because a `jnp.ndarray` is an `np.ndarray`.

As for why `bool`s, that's likely because your `jnp.array`s are missing generic parameters and the first valid overload for `__add__` on `np.ndarray` is

```
    @overload
    def __add__(self: NDArray[bool_], other: _ArrayLikeBool_co) -> NDArray[bool_]: ...  # type: ignore[misc]
```

so it's just defaulted to `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, JAX has very poor compatibility with mypy, because it's very difficult to satisfy mypy's constraints with JAX's transformation model, which often calls functions with transform-specific tracer values that act as stand-ins for arrays (See [How To Think in JAX: JIT Mechanics](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html#jit-mechanics-tracing-and-static-variables) for a brief discussion of this mechanism).

This use of tracer types as standins for arrays means that mypy will raise errors when strictly-typed JAX functions are transformed, and for this reason throughout the JAX codebase we tend to alias `Array` to `Any`, and use this as the return type annotation for JAX functions that return arrays.

It would be good to improve on this, because an `Any` return type is not very useful for effective type checking, but it's just the first of many challenges for making mypy play well with JAX. If you want to read some of the last few years worth of discussions surrounding this issue, I would start here: https://github.com/google/jax/issues/943

And in the meantime, my suggestion would be to use `Any` as a type annotation for JAX arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2023, it appears that `jax` has greatly improved its typing annotations. `mypy` is fine with the [new syntax](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.typing.html):

```
from jax import Array
from jax.typing import ArrayLike

import jax.numpy as jnp

def test(a: ArrayLike, b: ArrayLike) -> Array:
    return a + b
```